# Index section title not appearing when compiling dtx file

Tags: indexing, makeindex, dtx

I have a file called `_dtx.dtx` with the following code:

```
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[numbered]{hypdoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\IndexPrologue{}

\begin{document}
\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\PrintChanges
\PrintIndex
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \tableofcontents
%
% \changes{v1.0}{2022/10/24}{Some changes.}
%
% \section{Documentation of code}
%
% \iffalse
%<*package>
% \fi
%
%\begin{macro}{\a}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\a{\b}
\def\b{\c}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro}
% \iffalse
%</package>
% \fi
%\Finale
```

The issue is that I get the index itself, but there is no title:[image]

File `_dtx.ins`:

```
\input l3docstrip

\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse

\generate{\file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}}

\endbatchfile
```

Run:

```
pdftex _dtx.ins
pdflatex _dtx.dtx
pdflatex _dtx.dtx
makeindex -s gind.ist -o _dtx.ind _dtx.idx
makeindex -s gglo.ist -o _dtx.gls _dtx.glo
pdflatex _dtx.dtx
pdflatex _dtx.dtx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing the title with

```
 \IndexPrologue{}
```

Use e.g.

```
 \IndexPrologue{\section*{Index}}
```

instead.